# Django multiplechoicefield not rending on page

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to get a form that takes in a name and month and will return students with that name and month (attendance system). I'm using a MultipleChoiceField for the form but it does not render in the browser. I am also using Materialize CSS. How do I sort this issue? I'm also rendering the form fields manually.

forms.py:

```
class attendenceFinder(forms.Form):
    months = ((1, 'JAN'),
             (2, 'FEB'),
             (3, 'MAR'),
             (4, 'APR'),
             (5, 'MAY'),
             (6, 'JUN'),
             (7, 'JUL'),
             (8, 'AUG'),
             (9, 'SEP'),
             (10, 'OCT'),
             (11, 'NOV'),
             (12, 'DEC')
    )    

    name = forms.CharField()
    month = forms.MultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.SelectMultiple, choices=months)
```

attendence.html:

```
<form action="/get_attendence/", method="post">
<div class="container">
        {{ form.non_field_errors }}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.name.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.name.id_for_label }}">Name</label>
        {{ form.name }}
    </div>
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ form.month.errors }}
        <label for="{{ form.month.id_for_label }}">{{form.month}}
            <span>{{ form.month.label }}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
    <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn-large lime accent-2 black-text" type="submit" name="action">Submit
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
    </div>
</form>
```

Page source:

```
   <div class="fieldWrapper">

        <select name="month" required id="id_month" multiple>
  <option value="1">JAN</option>

  <option value="2">FEB</option>

  <option value="3">MAR</option>

  <option value="4">APR</option>

  <option value="5">MAY</option>

  <option value="6">JUN</option>

  <option value="7">JUL</option>

  <option value="8">AUG</option>

  <option value="9">SEP</option>

  <option value="10">OCT</option>

  <option value="11">NOV</option>

  <option value="12">DEC</option>

</select>
        <span>Month</span>

    </div>
```

The form in browser:

[image]

The name field renders fine but the Month multiple choice doesn't.

Comment: why are you wrapping the field inside the <label>?

Comment: I saw that in some other question and thought it might help with the rending because of Materialize CSS.

Comment: what does the HTML show in your browser? (just the part inside the <div class="fieldWrapper">)

Comment: I added a page source in the question. If that's what you wanted?

Comment: As you can see the options are there. You just shouldn’t put the <select> inside the <label>

Comment: Okay, I removed the label tags. Now it just says "Month" in black and nothing else.

Comment: Again look at the source to see what the browser sees

Comment: Checked, still looks same. I updated the source in the question too.

Comment: The select is there no reason you can’t see it

Comment: Yep, I don't get why it does not show up in the browser.

Comment: Debug your css in your developer tools. Is there css setting the display of select?

Comment: Sorry for the question, but how do I do that?

Comment: Well, putting in `class="browser-default"` via inspect element in Chrome makes the select appear. Doesn't look like Materialize CSS but how would I do that in my code?

Comment: On your `forms.py class attendanceFinder` add `month.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'browser-default'})`

Comment: Your css is hiding it so you should change your css. Inspect the css on the select element to figure out what’s causing it.

Comment: Think I fixed it by passing the following in forms.py: `month = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=months, widget=forms.Select(
            choices=months,
            attrs={'class': 'browser-default'}),)` it makes the select appear in browser.

Comment: That means that something in your CSS is hiding the `<select>`.

Comment: It's just the way Django renders its forms and how Materialize expects to render them. There if a fix by overwritting the widgets. I posted an answer I found. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Materialize CSS expects to see  tags with a class="browser-default". However Django forms do not add the class. So the following must be passed in forms.py:

```
class attendenceFinder(forms.Form):
    months = ((1, 'JAN'),
              (2, 'FEB'),
              (3, 'MAR'),
              (4, 'APR'),
              (5, 'MAY'),
              (6, 'JUN'),
              (7, 'JUL'),
              (8, 'AUG'),
              (9, 'SEP'),
              (10, 'OCT'),
              (11, 'NOV'),
              (12, 'DEC')
    )
 month = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=months, widget=forms.Select(
            choices=months,
            attrs={'class': 'browser-default'}))
```

**All credit goes to this link:**

https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/4904

Answer (score 1):

Django material very helpful for the form rendering that use Materializecss . Here is the link to project https://github.com/viewflow/django-material.